# How do I scrape food menu from zomato page?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape food menu data from zomato. I am using selenium to do the same while inspecting the elements, I can find the class 'category_heading', but using the same in the code gives no result and shows empty list. I am attaching the snippet of the code. Thanks.

I have tried using browser.find_element_by_xpath as well find_element_by_class_name and tag, but nothing seems to work.

```
order_now = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='orig-search-list']/div[1]/div[2]/a").click()
browser.maximize_window() 
browser.implicitly_wait(20) 
food_item = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("category_heading")
print('food',food_item)
```

I need the food menu data so that I can store it in a csv.

Comment: what error it shows when you execute this code?

Comment: It sometimes show "element not found" or it gives an empty list.

Comment: what the original url please?

Comment: Yaa Sure...the url is https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/burgers-kingdom-indiranagar-bangalore/order

Answer (score 0):

Page can be slow to load. Try using a wait condition

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/burgers-kingdom-indiranagar-bangalore/order')
rows = WebDriverWait(d, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".row")))    
soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')

for category in soup.select('.category-container'):
    title = category.select_one('h3').text
    print(title)
    items = [i.text for i in category.select('.category_heading')]
    if items:
        print(items)
    else:
        print('No sub-headers')
```

Comment: Hey...tried using the Wait condition, but still not getting any results. Did this script run for you?

Comment: yes it ran perfectly for me. Did you get a time out?

Comment: Its working fine now....it was the time issue that was happening. Thank you